# Who are Logicars and Despars?

Tags: word-meaning

In the movie "Pump Up the Volume" a high school teacher reads from a students story to her class:

```
"And so then the Logicars questioned the few remaining Despars more and more.
 They began to fade away until there was nothing left of them and they
 disappeared from the face of the Earth."
```

Searching the Internet I am unable to find the information of who the Logicars and Despars are. All the links I find lead to transcriptions of the movie. I guess "Logicars" have something to do with logic, but I really don't know what "Despars" are. There's not any context; the  teacher just read this quote to the class and then says the student is a good writer and should to send his stories to publishers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the identity of fictitious proper names.  It is not about English-language learning.

Comment: Well there are cases when an OP can not understand a video and asks for help which do not get closed, I always get confused about what's allowed and what's not allowed. There's also a cultural aspect to the way the scene is setup so I don't think the down votes are necessary in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th context is within the movie itself, do not get hung up on the literal story that the teacher is reading [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vueUt85epAA&t=10m25s).

The story that the teacher was written by Mark (aka Happy Harry Hardon / Christian Slater) who is an outcast after moving to a "vanilla" community in Arizona.

The passage reflects his feeling of being outside the community he lives in. He is a rebel and runs a pirate radio station every night from 10:00pm.

The "Logicars" represent the rest of the "vanilla" community, and Mark identifies as a "Deathspar". The words are made up. Mark is taking pride in being different and feels oppressed with the inevitable apocalyptic ending that most teenagers envision. A major clue is the teacher's comment of "leading with your heart not your mind".